# com.japisoft.formula.node.EvaluateException: Wrong operand for the binary operator /

Tags: java, exception, evaluate

I am getting following exception while running my Java application :

```
com.japisoft.formula.node.EvaluateException: Wrong operand for the binary operator /
```

Actually this is a legacy project of my organization and we use `japisoft libraries`. Few days back I was able to run the project but now facing this issue and `www.japisoft.com` is not accessible.

I have checked all Operands used for the evaluation and those have correct values.

I'm getting this error for almost all binary operators like `*, /, +, -` etc.

Can anyone help for this ?

Comment: Is there more stacktrace? Are you using some of these methods: http://www.japisoft.com/formula/javadoc/com/japisoft/formula/node/class-use/EvaluateException.html ?

Comment: Yes I am using evaluate() method and following is the stack trace.

com.japisoft.formula.node.EvaluateException: Wrong operand for the binary operator /
 at com.japisoft.formula.node.BinaryOperatorNode.evaluate(SourceFile:34)
 at com.japisoft.formula.node.GroupNode.evaluate(SourceFile:41)
 at com.japisoft.formula.node.RootNode.evaluate(SourceFile:22)
 at com.japisoft.formula.Formula.evaluate(SourceFile:428)

Comment: In the docs there are other methods like eval(). Can you add the NodeContext value to the comment?

Comment: Docs are not opening but I didn't see any methods to get NodeContext and eval().
It has only evaluate(), getValueForFunction(), getValueForSymbol(), getExpression(), getOperatorFactory() etc.

Comment: Can you add the NodeContext value to the comment?